# A package R for normal-reference bandwidth selector

Tags: r, kernel, bandwidth

I use kernel smoothing for estimating the area under curve of ROC curve in R 
 using `kroc` in `library(ks)`

```
x <- rnorm(16,mean = 0,sd = 1)
y <- rnorm(24,mean = 1,sd = 1)

auc.kernel <- kroc(x1 = x,x2 = y)
auc.kernel$incidence$auc
```

I want to use normal-reference bandwidth selector who proposed by Hall and Hyndmann (2003) for my `kroc` estimation. But in `library(ks)` there is no
command for using it. What is package to use the normal-reference bandwidth selector for my kernel smoothing?